# Collada model does not render when applying a texture

Tags: three.js, collada

When I try to apply a texture to my `.dae` model, it is not rendered and the console displays this error:

```
    [.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : 
      glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2
```

This happens when I add the following code to my `collada loader` :

```
loader.load( 'models/walls.dae', function ( collada ) {
var colladaWalls = collada.scene.children[0]
colladaWalls.name = "walls";
var wallsTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/walls.jpg' );
wallsTexture.wrapS = wallsTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
wallsTexture.repeat.set( 2, 2 );
//adding the line below cause the model to not be loaded
colladaWalls.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: wallsTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } ); 
colladaWalls.material.needsUpdate = true;
colladaWalls.material.wireframe = false;
colladaWalls.position.set(0,-2,0);//x,z,y- if you think in blender dimensions ;)
colladaWalls.scale.set(2,2,2);
scene.add( colladaWalls ); 
} );
```

**Question:** Why?

Answer (score 0):

`MeshPhongMaterial()` requires more attributes. Try using `MeshBasicMaterial()`

Comment: Doesn't change anything. The problem lays when I try to change the material using ThreeJS to an imported model .dae. Is this some kind of limit to Collada or to ThreeJS?